# Move checkbox's text to the box

Tags: android, checkbox

I want to remove the texts that are next to check boxes and fill the boxes background with text instead. I attached an image of how I want the view to be.

[image]
In the second part ( Working Times) Those are dates of the week, how can I achieve something like that? Thank you

Comment: Where is your check boxes, What text need to be clear. Explain with more detail

Comment: Hello, I want it to be like in Working times, where the dates are each separated checkbox, with custom look like that. However, I was able to achieved it without using checkboxes, but using the way that you suggested below

Answer (score 1):

You can use Horzontal LinearLayout and TextView instead of check boxes

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_food_type"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:layout_below="@id/ll_image_content"
                android:background="@drawable/food_type_shadow"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_Monday"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="#eeeeee"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:paddingStart="4dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:text="@string/monday"
                        android:textColor="#000" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_tue"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:background="#eeeeee"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:paddingStart="4dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:text="@string/tuesday"
                        android:textColor="#000" />
                </LinearLayout>

             </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a great idea! However, it wasn't really what I was asking, so I'm not gonna mark your answer as the selected one. I gave you an up-vote anyway, thanks a lot